# I can not able to use overflow: hidden proprty in email-template for outlook(mobile view)

Tags: html, css, email-templates

```
<div style="width: 640px; max-height: 587px; background: #fcf6f5; overflow: hidden;">
         <table style="background: #fcf6f5; opacity: 0.8;border-spacing: 0;padding: 0;">
             <tr>
                 <td style="width: 640px; height: 175px; text-align: center; padding: 0;"><img src="https://f28a-103-251-217-212.in.ngrok.io/image/image.png" alt="mailImage" border="0" style="width: 100px;padding: 60px 0 31px;"></td>
             </tr>
         </table>
</div>
```

My div is overflowing in spite of given width(for mobile view)
It is working good on gmail and other providers.

Comment: add reproducible code with your question

Comment: Some css properties are not supported when sending email template, That might be the case. check if your element has `overflow` property. If not, that means that outlook doesn't support `overflow`.